# How to print function call backtrace in android Chromium?

Tags: android, chromium

Is there a way to print the function call backtrace in Android Chromium? I want to check the function call fluent.

The following url provided by `bitchainer` show the answer:
https://www.chromium.org/blink/getting-started-with-blink-debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is exiting interfaces in the chromium itself to print the backtrace in android chromium, you can try the following methods:

```
//Add Header File
#include <base/debug/stack_trace.h>

//use it in the place where need to print the backtrace
base::debug::StackTrace st;
st.Print();
```

And you can reference the following link:

https://www.chromium.org/blink/getting-started-with-blink-debugging

Comment: You may need to set the following compile flags : exclude_unwind_tables=true

Comment: It's also possible the standard output isn't being redirected to `adb logcat`. Try this using:

#include "base/logging.h"
LOG(WARNING) << st.ToString();

Keep in mind that you'll have to symbolize the stack trace.
 
Personally, I've found attaching gdb and printing stacktraces that way to be more effective.

Comment: can't work in my case